# Any way to receive DAB radio on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: radio, rtl-sdr

I've been looking around and can't seem to find something where someone has got DAB radio working on the Raspberry Pi with an RTL-SDR. It seems possible, as the RTL-SDR is fully capable of receiving DAB, I just need to know if software exists to decode it on the Raspberry Pi.